# Ordering bar plots with ggplot2 according to their size, i.e. numerical value

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, bar-chart

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph) asks about ordering a bar graph according to an unsummarized table. I have a slightly different situation. Here's part of my original data:

```
experiment,pvs_id,src,hrc,mqs,mcs,dmqs,imcs
dna-wm,0,7,9,4.454545454545454,1.4545454545454546,1.4545454545454541,4.3939393939393945
dna-wm,1,7,4,2.909090909090909,1.8181818181818181,0.09090909090909083,3.9090909090909087
dna-wm,2,7,1,4.818181818181818,1.4545454545454546,1.8181818181818183,4.3939393939393945
dna-wm,3,7,8,3.4545454545454546,1.5454545454545454,0.4545454545454546,4.272727272727273
dna-wm,4,7,10,3.8181818181818183,1.9090909090909092,0.8181818181818183,3.7878787878787876
dna-wm,5,7,7,3.909090909090909,1.9090909090909092,0.9090909090909092,3.7878787878787876
dna-wm,6,7,0,4.909090909090909,1.3636363636363635,1.9090909090909092,4.515151515151516
dna-wm,7,7,3,3.909090909090909,1.7272727272727273,0.9090909090909092,4.030303030303029
dna-wm,8,7,11,3.6363636363636362,1.5454545454545454,0.6363636363636362,4.272727272727273
```

I only need a few variables from this, namely `mqs` and `imcs`, grouped by their `pvs_id`, so I create a new table:

```
m = melt(t, id.var="pvs_id", measure.var=c("mqs","imcs"))
```

I can plot this as a bar graph where one can see the correlation between *MQS* and *IMCS*.

```
ggplot(m, aes(x=pvs_id, y=value)) 
+ geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

However, I'd like the **resulting bars to be ordered by the *MQS* value**, from left to right, in decreasing order. The *IMCS* values should be ordered with those, of course.

How can I accomplish that? Generally, given any molten dataframe — which seems useful for graphing in ggplot2 and today's the first time I've stumbled over it — how do I specify the order for one variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all in making

`pvs_id` a factor and supplying the appropriate levels to it:

```
dat$pvs_id <- factor(dat$pvs_id, levels = dat[order(-dat$mqs), 2])

m = melt(dat, id.var="pvs_id", measure.var=c("mqs","imcs"))

ggplot(m, aes(x=pvs_id, y=value))+ 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Well since `pvs_id` was numeric it is treated in an ordered fashion.  Where as if you have a factor no order is assumed.  So even though you have numeric labels `pvs_id` is actually a factor (nominal).  And as far as `dat[order(-dat$mqs), 2]` is concerned the order function with a negative sign orders the data frame from largest to smallest along the variable `mqs`.  But you're interested in that order for the `pvs_id` variable so you index that column which is the second column.  If you tear that apart you'll see it gives you:

```
> dat[order(-dat$mqs), 2]
[1] 6 2 0 5 7 4 8 3 1
```

Now you supply that to the `levels` argument of `factor` and this orders the factor as you want it.

Comment: PS don't name a data set t as it writes over a pretty important base install function that transposes.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. It can tell data sets from functions. Try it: `t <- 1:5; t(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))`. If you were to say `t <- function(x) 1:x`, you would get into trouble, though.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm not really into the nomenclature here so I wasn't aware of what "factors" were. And `dat[order(-dat$mqs), 2]` returns the `pvs_id` values in order of decreasing `mqs`, right? How exactly does that work? Would you mind explaining that part a little more, so future visitors might be able to adapt this more easily?

Answer (score 0):

With newer `tidyverse` functions, this becomes much more straightforward (or at least, easy to read for me):

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  mutate_at("pvs_id", as.factor) %>%
  mutate(pvs_id = fct_reorder(pvs_id, mqs)) %>%
  gather(variable, value, c(mqs, imcs)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = pvs_id, y = value)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = variable), position = position_dodge())
```

What it does is:

- create a factor if not already
- reorder it according to `mqs` (you may use `desc(mqs)` for reverse-sorting)
- gather into individual rows (same as `melt`)
- plot as `geom_col` (same as `geom_bar` with `stat="identity"`)

[image]